# Unity C# Rigidbody vs Game Object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm currently making a game in which I do not plan on adding any physics to the player. Player will be moved simply by modifying the position and rotation directly through code on a grid. Should my player be a Game Object instead of a Rigidbody? Or something else entirely? I'm a little new to Unity and don't quite know what would be best for the player.

Comment: It will always be a GameObject. That's the "entity" to which you attach components (derived from MonoBehaviour) which define its behaviour. A RigidBody would be such a component. And you can write your own. 
If you don't need physics, you can do without a RigidBody. Although ultimately you might want to use it depending on how you handle collisions and the like. But nothing prevents you from starting without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your player is always a **GameObject**, your player can't be of type **RigidBody** If i understand your question right you want to know if it's better to use a **RigidBody** or a custom script tomove your player ?

*For easier use*, if you are new to unity i would advice you to use the **Rigidbody**. You simply *disable the gravity on it*. If you go for a custom **GameObject** it's going to be *more flexible* but you will have *more work* to do (like collisions, movement calculation, etc...). You can disable the gravity on a Rigidbody with **"useGravity = false"** via code or in the inspector.

**If you want to make your own script:**

**Here is a video than will explain how to do it:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiZ4z4qKy44&t=246s&ab_channel=Comp-3Interactive

**else:**

**Rigidbody Docs:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html

Hope it help. Have a nice day !